# How do you extend an Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have the following object:

```
Test.Beta.MyObject = function($) {

  var foo = {};

  foo.blah = function(attribute, validation) {
    if (attribute === "yey") {
      return false;
    }
      return true;
    };

  return foo;
}(jQuery);
```

How do I keep the above file in place, and extend the object somewhere else? **How do I insert this new method of foo in another file**....

```
foo.bar = function(attribute, validation) {
        if (attribute === "moo") {
          return false;
        }
          return true;
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding it to the prototype of your object is going to be the best bet if you intend to be able to call it for every instance of `MyObject`:

```
Test.Beta.MyObject.prototype.bar = function(attribute, validation) {
        if (attribute === "moo") {
          return false;
        }
          return true;
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Test.Beta.MyObject = function($) {
  // old code
  .....
  foo.extend = function (fn) {
     foo.prototype = fn;
  }

  return foo;
}(jQuery);
```